# how to make boundary line have also a border of black color using Qpainter

Tags: qt, qpainter

I am using **Qt**. I used `QPainter` to make boundary line. But I want boundary line have also a 1 pixel broad border so it visible more.

The following image shows the yellow border with black boundary.
this image is reference for the logic. i will applied it on random shaped

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Create a smaller rect from your boundingbox.

```
QRect adjusted(int dx1, int dy1, int dx2, int dy2) const

QRect smallerbox = boundingRect().adjusted(boundingRect.topLeft().x() +1, boundingRect.topLeft().y() +1, boundingRect.bottomRight().x() -1, boundingRect.bottomRight().y() -1);
```

Comment: i want to apply on **random** shaped item